# Delphi NT Service as a Client (not server), OnExecute vs OnStart

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I need to implement a Windows NT Service with Delphi as a part of my project.
Before starting the implementation (program has been finished and is waiting only for this), due to the complexity of the task (and my reduced knowledge in "system things"), I would be very grateful to anyone who can give me an idea on the subject.

Before presenting my question, I will say a few words on the nature on the project:
What I am writing in Delphi is a program that reads the NT Event Viewer logs and sends them somewhere else. Due to the automation of the thing, I have been asked to implement this as a Windows NT Service. 
I must underline that this service is NOT a Server of any kind (TCP, SMTP...). It will serve only as a Client - read the logs and send them. Thus (I think) I need no multi-treading, and I am happy for this because multi-threaded programming is a "big bone" for many, me included. I want to run this "routine" to some range between every 10 sec and 1 min. Under this conditions the task of reading NT Event Viewer records (from the last one send) will be normally short, few seconds, but in some cases it may be long (1 min or more) - when the service has stopped (or failed) for sometime and un-sent records have been accumulated. In this later case the operator will be instructed in documentation not to Stop the Service (at least no Terminate) until it finishes the current transport - this can be seen in some text debug file that is updated.

I have read many times almost all articles related on this site, especially the two below:

1. "delphi service application stop after 15 second, timer not executing" thank you very much here for advising the non-usage of TTimer and also for the second article as
2. "Tutorial for making a Service Application using Delphi" by Finn Tolderlund

Now exactly based into this article 2, my questions is:

Question:
In my conditions - Can I go for the OnExecute solution?

I wish I could, as I (think!) I need no multi-threading; and it is much simpler in code.

best regards
Altin

Comment: Windows already can forward eventlogs to other destinations, why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: because I need to extract info from fields and turn them to columns. extraction is specific to the info I am looking for
best regards,
Altin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stay away from the `TService.OnExecute` event. It is very easy to code it wrong and deadlock the service from responding to SCM requests.

Use the `TService.OnStart` event to start a worker thread, and the `TService.On(Stop|Shutdown)` events to terminate that thread. The thread can run a loop that handles (re)opening the connection to the destination, and reading+forwarding the log entries as needed.

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. Lebeau!

Can I be protected from OnExecute deadlock-ing by the fact that my jobs does not call for multi-threading (at least on itself), ie there is no Server?
Or any guidelines on how not to fail with OnExecute?

And if I am hopeless with my OnExecute, can you indicate any example with the OnStart?
I could find a complete example, missing in the Tutorial

thanks and regards
Altin

Do the dangers of using the OnExecute method consist to the capability of multi-threading (serving many clients), or to the duration of the scheduled job?

Comment: The problem with using `TService.OnExecute` is that it requires you to *manually* call `TService.ServiceThread.ProcessRequests()` at regular intervals. Most `TService` beginners don't do that, and then wonder why their services don't respond to the SCM correctly. If you don't assign a `TService.OnExecute` handler, `TService` calls `ProcessRequests()` internally for you, and all is good in the world. That is why I always say to *never* use the `TService.OnExecute` event, *always* use a worker thread instead.

Comment: Thank you very much for advising dear Mr Lebeau,

I will try to use the OnStart event see where I get. I will put all my code logic into a TDM which will be created (and released) in Runtime.

One more question here please:
If I work the way above, do the TTimer limitations (non usage in Service to be more precise) still persist ?
I am asking this because this way I could just have a simple DM create/FreeAndNil into the OnStart and OnStop events; and have a "normal" Delphi job into the DM with a usual TTimer; and avoid complicated code (for me) into OnStart/Stop 

best regards
Altin

Comment: You don't need a separate `TDataModule`, as `TService` itself is a `TDataModule` descendant

Comment: And yes, `TTimer` has issues in a service. At runtime, `TService` is created in the main thread but runs in a worker thread. If you create the `TTimer` at design-time, it will run in the main thread, so you have to make sure your `OnTimer` handler is thread-safe. Otherwise, to run `OnTimer` in the service thread, you have to create the `TTimer` in the `OnStart` event, but creating `TTimer` outside of the main thread is not thread-safe. Better to have `OnExecute` (or a separate thread) use a loop with a [waitable timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687012.aspx)

Comment: thank you very much Sir

but isn't in my case (timer work is thread-safe!), everything reduced to?

1.create a new Delphi Service Application
2.place the TTimer (desing-time) into the TService (timer work is thread-safe!)
3. set the the timer.interval at TService.OnCreate according to some .ini value and set its Enabled:=true

best regards
Altin

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160138/discussion-between-remy-lebeau-and-altink).